# How to find out the max / latest multi dimensional arrays

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, max, min

I have these arrays, [270] [269] [268] are album ID, and [94] [86] [96] [101] ... are photo ID. how to find out the max means the latest photo in each album. 
My purpose is looping all the photos, find out the max photo and style it larger than others in each album. Btw, I set both album and photo value as key in this arrays. Is this good or bad?
Thanks in adv

```
so the result is:
Album 1 = $arr[270][97]
Album 2 = $arr[269][102]
Album 3 = $arr[268][86]

Array
(
[270] => Array
    (
        [user_email] => aaa@hotmail.com
        [story_name] => Story C
        [89] => Array
            (
                [pid] => 89
                [photo_url] => story_photos/2012/0322/361332393792911587.jpg
            )

        [90] => Array
            (
                [pid] => 90
                [photo_url] => story_photos/2012/0322/361332393792911587.jpg
            )

        [97] => Array
            (
                [pid] => 92
                [photo_url] => story_photos/2012/0402/361333367180912960.jpg
            )
      )
[269] => Array
    (
        [user_email] => aaa@hotmail.com
        [story_name] => Story B
        [87] => Array
            (
                [pid] => 87
                [photo_url] => story_photos/2012/0322/361332381406580761.jpg
            )

        [98] => Array
            (
                [pid] => 98
                [photo_url] => story_photos/2012/0402/361333369100507620.jpg
            )

        [102] => Array
            (
                [pid] => 99
                [photo_url] => story_photos/2012/0402/361333369110530609.jpg
            )
[268] => Array
    (
        [user_email] => aaa@hotmail.com
        [story_name] => Story A
        [86] => Array
            (
                [pid] => 86
                [photo_url] => story_photos/2012/0322/361332381393552719.jpg
            )

    )

)
```

Comment: How do you define the "max" photo? is their any property we can use, such as the largest pid?

Comment: This is what i feel weird there is no property can use so i ask is this arrays structure good or poor. And yes the [pid] is also the key

Comment: Is the largest key always the newest photo? Because in my world it's not guaranteed to be.

Comment: omg, thanks for remind me, actually i got another key under [photo_url] which is [photo_added_date] so the largest [photo_added_date] is the newest photo.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you use something like the following array structure:

```
Array (
[270] => Array (
        [user_email] => aaa@hotmail.com
        [story_name] => Story C
        [photos] => Array(
            [89] => Array
                (
                    [pid] => 89
                    [photo_url] => story_photos/2012/0322/361332393792911587.jpg
                )

            [90] => Array
                (
                    [pid] => 90
                    [photo_url] => story_photos/2012/0322/361332393792911587.jpg
                )
        )
.
.
.
[269] => Array (...
)
```

and get the latest photo by using [krsort()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.krsort.php). like so:

```
foreach($array as $album) {
    krsort($album['photos']);
    for($i=0; $i<count($album['photos']); $i++) {
        if ($i == 0) {
            // LATEST
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: how do i create another array before it?  like what you mention ['photos'].

Answer (score 0):

You can use one of functions provided in on php.net (http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.min.php)

```
    function min_by_key($arr, $key)
    {
        $min = array();
        foreach ($arr as $val) {
            if (!isset($val[$key]) and is_array($val)) 
            {
                $min2 = min_by_key($val, $key);
                $min[$min2] = 1;
            } 
            elseif (!isset($val[$key]) and !is_array($val)) 
            {
                return false;
            } 
            elseif (isset($val[$key])) 
            {
                $min[$val[$key]] = 1;
            }
        }
        return min( array_keys($min) );
    }
```

---

```
    function max_by_key($arr, $key)
    {
        $max = array();
        foreach ($arr as $val) {
            if (!isset($val[$key]) and is_array($val)) 
            {
                $max2 = max_by_key($val, $key);
                $max[$max2] = 1;
            } 
            elseif (!isset($val[$key]) and !is_array($val)) 
            {
                return false;
            } 
            elseif (isset($val[$key])) 
            {
                $max[$val[$key]] = 1;
            }
        }
        return max( array_keys($max) );
    }
```